# PowerApps - Network error when using Patch function: The specified column is read-only and can't be modified

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

[image]

A colleague of mine encountered an error when updating an item in PowerApps. I tried to replicate the error in the dev environment, but the error didn't occur. The error given is not giving me much details on where to locate the read-only column stated.

Is there any way to provide a much-detailed error notification in PowerApps? That way I can easily locate where the root cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Select `App` in the Tree View, and add the following to the `On Error` property:

```
Notify( Concat(Error(YourSPList), Column & ": " & Message), NotificationType.Error)
```

Hopefully that will tell you which column(s) is causing the error.
You could also look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/monitor-collaborative-debugging

I suspect the issue is that user doesn't have edit permissions on the list - or - in the List Advanced Settings, under Item-Level Permissions - it is set to  "Create items and edit items that we created by the user", meaning the user can only edit the items that they created.